# method x has no supported translation to SQL when use a static class

Tags: c#, linq

I am using MVC platform and a jqGrid in the views. below is the part of controller code return json to the grid

```
IQueryable<CalendarViewModel> callendars =
            from call in (new KYTCDataContext()).Calendars
            where call.AcademicYear == id
            select Matcher.Calendar(call);

        if (jqGridParameters._search != false)
        {
            callendars = callendars.Where(jqGridParameters.WhereClause);
        }

        if (jqGridParameters.sidx != null)
            callendars = callendars.OrderBy(
                jqGridParameters.sidx.Substring(8) + " " + jqGridParameters.sord.ToLower());
        var count = callendars.Count();
        int pageIndex = jqGridParameters.page;
```

the Matcher is a static class. below is the used method of the class

```
public static class Matcher
    { 
public static CalendarViewModel Calendar(Calendar call)
        {
            return new CalendarViewModel
            {
                ID = call.ID,
                Name = call.Name,
                StartDate = call.StartDate,
                EndDate = call.EndDate,
                AcademicYear = call.AcademicYear
            };
        }
}
```

at the line

```
var count = callendars.Count();
```

i recieve this error:

*Method 'KYTC.Models.CalendarViewModel Calendar(KYTC.Data.Calendar)' has no supported translation to SQL.*

but when I change the LINQ query to this:

```
IQueryable<CalendarViewModel> callendars =
            from call in (new KYTCDataContext()).Calendars
            where call.AcademicYear == id
            select new CalendarViewModel
            {
                ID = call.ID,
                Name = call.Name,
                StartDate = call.StartDate,
                EndDate = call.EndDate,
                AcademicYear = call.AcademicYear
            };
```

my code is running well.

**what is wrong with my class definition?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your class definition. The problem is that you simply can't call arbitrary functions in Linq-to-SQL (or EntityFramework) queries. Only a handful of predefined methods can be translated into SQL syntax. Your final method is the correct way of returning `CalendarViewModel` objects from a query.

However, you could also do this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Calendar, CalendarViewModel>> CalendarExpression()
{
    return c => new CalendarViewModel
    {
        ID = c.ID,
        Name = c.Name,
        StartDate = c.StartDate,
        EndDate = c.EndDate,
        AcademicYear = c.AcademicYear
    };
}

var calendarExpr = Match.CalendarExpression();
IQueryable<CalendarViewModel> callendars =
    (from call in (new KYTCDataContext()).Calendars
     where call.AcademicYear == id
     select call)
    .Select(calendarExpr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have alot of chaning in my code now ==> go to work.